# Azure devops deployment of azure function app creating extra folder in wwwroot

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I had created azure function app with private endpoints. I created self host agent VM and pushed my ZIP file to same VNET that storage account, function app, VM resides. After deploying ,I see an extra folder inside `wwwroot` folder. Not sure what am doing wrong.

I am using classical pipeline approach.

**Build Pipeline:**

[image]

**Release pipelines :**

Option1: Tried with Azure CLI Task by deploying.

[image]

Option2: Tried with Azure FUnction App Deploy Task

[image]

Creating bin,function1,json files are inside "build" folder which should not be occurred.

**Expected Output:** All the files must be deploy under root folder.

[image]

**Update:** Based on comments suggested, I tried to reproduce the issue and fixed.

Before Issue fix: The azure function app code files resides inside `build` folder that downloaded build.zip artifact from build pipeline as show in below screenshot.

As my Azure CLI Task is deploying entire zip as it is, it is showing build folder under `wwwrooot`.

[image]

[image]

**Changes done to CI pipeline:**

Copy files from wwwroot/build folder to wwwroot using `Pipeline Copy file task`

[image]

Next In archive files Task i modified `rootFolderOrFile` to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/build`

After CI pipeline runs, I again downloaded ZIP file to make sure ther is no `build` folder inside it. And it worked like a champ :)

Comment: Did you zip the build folder?

Comment: @dacastr Yes , I did build zip folder successful. CI pipeline is success.

Comment: What I mean is that it looks like you zipped the build folder instead of zipping the individual components below it. That seems to be why bin, Function1, and host.json are not at the root of the directory.

Comment: I did very straight forward approach for build and release pipelines. The only customization is ```build\``` in archive files task in CI pipeline.

Comment: Have you tried following this guide? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-azure-devops?tabs=csharp%2Cyaml&pivots=v1

Comment: @PavanKumarGVVS, please download your build.zip artifact from build pipeline and show the screenshot of its structure, `expand` the wwwroot folders in screenshot., does it contain `build` already? Please update your function app task screenshot as it shows azure cli task actually.  In addition, there are several `build` in your definition, suggest to use `build1`, `build2` ...to help check where it comes in release deployment.

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT Yes thats what exactly I did and it worked fine for me now. Thanks for your input

Comment: @PavanKumarGVVS, glad to know it helps! You can mark the similar answer below from KKI as it's resolved by fixing the zip structure, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test my observation now, but I would first check the "`rootFolderOrFile`" line in the yaml code of the build pipeline.

You can make settings something like this with a deploy task:

```
- task: ExtractFiles
  displayName: 'Extract Website from Zip'
  inputs:
    archiveFilePatterns: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/xy.zip'
    destinationFolder: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    cleanDestinationFolder: true
    overwriteExistingFiles: false
```

When you make a zip and unzip it, it creates a folder (which is also the name of the zip) and puts the unzipped files in it.

———

EDIT: Okay, I see that you have `includeRootFolder: false` line but check the structure of your ZIP file to make sure it directly contains the files instead of an additional root folder.

———

Workaround: In your current case, you will have to copy file from `wwwroot/build` folder to `wwwroot` using Pipeline `Copy file` task and after it you can delete the build folder with `Delete files` task.

Comment: I tried alternative approach and it worked for me :)

Comment: I am glad to hear. If my answer was helpful please don't forget to rate it with an upvote :)